# Is it possible to customise the border width of windows in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, display-settings

Even though Windows 7 has thinner window borders than Windows Vista, they still bug me. Is there any way to reduce their width? Right now they're roughly 10 pixels wide and I'd like to make them, say, 3 pixels.

Answer (score 6):

1. Right click an empty part of your desktop and choose `Personalize`

[image]

2. Click `Window color`

[image]

3. Click `Advanced appearance settings`

[image]

4. Scroll down to `Border Padding` and change the width.
   [image]

Comment: and this is what it looks like with really narrow borders - http://i447.photobucket.com/albums/qq194/akadruid/narrowborders.png

Comment: I tried setting this to 0 and the border width for the Window Color and Appearance dialogue changed to what Colin Pickard posted, but all the other bigger windows remained the same. :(

Answer (score 0):

[Ultimate Windows Tweaker](http://www.winvistaclub.com/Ultimate_Windows_Tweaker.html) is able to do this. It's in `Personalization`, called `Change window padding size`. Note that for some reason it's not in pixels.

Answer (score 0):

[GIGATweaker](http://www.7room.net/gigatweaker/) is another app that does this and much more.