# How to change border width in MS Windows to grab and resize it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, border, mouse-acceleration

I have a wide monitor (3440 x 1440). My mouse is set to max pointer speed with enhance pointer precision is enabled in order to minimize how far I have to physically move the mouse to get the pointer from one end of the screen to the other. These mouse settings make it hard to grab a window border to resize the window. Is there any way to increase the 'grab' size of a window?

Answer (score 7):

There are two registry keys in Windows 7 - 11 that control the border 'grab' width: BorderWidth and PaddedBorderWidth, in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`. They also affect the title bar height. The max combined value for both keys is -1500. A higher number won't cause an error on Windows 11 (Test 3 below) but also won't increase the grab or title bar size.

Neither of these keys changes the visual size of the 1 pixel border around the sides and bottom of a window on Windows 11. Consensus on the internet says it's not possible. On Windows 10, you can try the AeroLite theme ([instructions here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/in-windows-10-how-can-i-increase-the-border/a2f124dd-3678-4f16-b08f-476ebf118937)).

**TEST 1: PaddedBorderWidth Only (value -1000; default -60)**

- Grab size is 45 pixels around sides and bottom of window
- Visual size of title bar is 83 pixels for many windows (not office apps, chrome, edge)
- Vertical window dividers were 45 pixels for some apps (regedit) but not others (MS management console, file explorer)

**TEST 2: BorderWidth Only (value -1000; default -15)**

- Grab size is 26 pixels around sides and bottom of window
- Visual size of title bar is 67 pixels
- Affected function of the title bar, making it impossible to click the minimize, expand, and close icons in UWP apps (calculator, snipping tool, clock, photos, etc.) but not others (office apps, wordpad, chrome, edge)

**TEST 3: PaddedBorderWidth and BorderWidth (both at -1000)**

- Grab size is 87 pixels around sides and bottom of window
- Visual size of title bar is 125 pixels

Miscellany:

- Resizing UWP apps from the title bar only works on the right side near the minimize icon
- Some apps (snipping tool) can be sized very small (height, top to bottom). In this case, the grab bar size in the registry is ignored until the window's size is increased.
- Neither of these registry keys affect MS Edge in WDAG (Windows Defender Application Guard). It runs in a HyperV VM, so maybe these keys are ignored by HyperV.
- Some of the above info came from MS answers [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/window-borders/e039f5dd-a84f-411b-a94a-02c24566fdfa?page=1) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/in-windows-10-how-can-i-increase-the-border/a2f124dd-3678-4f16-b08f-476ebf118937)

Linking related questions to make this information easier to find:

- [Windows 10 high contrast border width](https://superuser.com/questions/1245178/windows-10-high-contrast-border-width)
- [Increase width of drag handles W10](https://superuser.com/questions/971794/increase-width-of-drag-handles-w10)
- [Is it possible to customise the border width of windows in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/177862/is-it-possible-to-customise-the-border-width-of-windows-in-windows-7)
- [How do I increase the size of the titlebar and window border padding on Windows 8?](https://superuser.com/questions/712483/how-do-i-increase-the-size-of-the-titlebar-and-window-border-padding-on-windows)
- [How to change window border width in Chrome?](https://superuser.com/questions/1563357/how-to-change-window-frame-border-width-in-google-chrome-on-win-7)

Comment: Note: the registry key is `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`

Comment: Oversight on my part not to include, but now added. Thanks.

Comment: also, those "15" and "60" figures are in pixels times 15 (i.e. 1 and 4 pixels). I read that somewhere in the docs. these figures describe the "hitbox" relative to the window.